# Magento 2 - Custom Variables API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, custom-variable

I was wondering if there is an API for the Custom Variables in Magento under `System > Other Settings > Custom Variables`.

Going through the `System > Integrations > API lists` it as Available APIs. But I cannot find it anywhere in the swagger doc.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_23.html#/

Comment: You want to pass custom variables in Magento 2 rest API. Right?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to add/update Custom Variables thru API.